# PHP Trim first 5 characters + semi-colon

Tags: php

Here is my string:

```
usercss:body background: red, #header: background: #fff;
```

I want to remove `usercss:`

```
body background: red, #header: background: #fff;
```

Then `explode` by `, (comma)` to produce a list like so:

```
body {
background: red;
}
#header {
background: #fff;
}
```

Might be tricky to get the curly brackets in {} but if somebody could help me explode it into a list like:

```
body background: red; #heeader background: #fff;
```

That would be a great help!

Comment: Why is there a semicolon after `#header` but not after `body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content=substr($content,strlen('usercss:'));
$arr=split(",",$content);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be strlen('usercss:') ?

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP5.3 you can also use http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

```
$content = strstr($content, 'usercss', true);
```

instead of `substr`.